# Ajax image upload submit conflict with form ajax - make .submit() function work for that form only

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, jquery

In the middle of a multi-page form, i have a section where the user can upload an image, and that image is previews straight away using ajax. However, when the user uploads the image, the actual form itself also tries to submit, and i think there is an ajax conflict. This is the code i am using for the ajax image upload:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#logo').live('change', function()            { 
        $("#prlogo").html('');
        $("#prlogo").html('<img src="../preview/loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
        $("#logoform").ajaxForm({
            target: '#prlogo'
        }).submit();
    });
});
```

And this is the form:

```
<form id="logoform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='../preview/logo.php'>
    <input type="file" name="logo" id="logo" />
</form>
```

Is it possible to link that .submit() to the form with id logoform? Is there any other way i can limit the submit to work only for the image upload and not the form?

Answer (score 0):

You could try overriding the submit function of the form, so before you call submit, you would need to set something like the below

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action, type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(), cache: false,
        success: function () {
            //Do upload of Image
           }
        }

        //Or upload image here
    });
```